# How to post single in jquery ajax, after all events finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are accordion panels, each panel has its own variables in javascript.

**I want to save data from each panel in jQuery using something like transaction or queue of POST requests.**

Every panel binds its own event to `onSave` click by preparing the data.

```
//panel1 that prepares the data
$("#save").click(function() {
  globalvar['panel1'] = 'somedata';
});
//panel2 prepares the data
$("#save").click(function() {
  globalvar['panel2'] = 2*21+11;
});
```

How can I make AJAX request, after all panels has been prepared their data?

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure as well?

Comment: @JudeDuran http://jsfiddle.net/igos/LLeuY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: Suppose your panel's data aren't loaded onLoad,
add a class to each panel. This class means that data hasn't been loaded yet for specific panel

```
<div class="noDataLoaded"></div>
```

Remove that class when data is loaded

```
$("#save").click(function() {
  //code to load data
  //Adjust according to your HTML structure 
  $(this).removeClass("noDataLoaded"); //encapsulate this when it has succeeded loading. 
  groupPost();
});
```

Function that checks if all data has been loaded

```
   function groupPost() {
     if($(".noDataLoaded").length == 0){
       $.ajax({
        //code
       });
      }
    }
```

`groupPost()` will only fire if there are no elements that's using `noDataLoaded` class and that only happens if you click all the panels and loaded its data.

Comment: Yes, this could be one of the solutions. I thought jQuery has a plugin for it.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! I've checked jquery accordion and it seems that there's no easy way to achieve your goal. You have to find another workaround if your'e not satisfied with the answers in this thread.. Please post your answer if you found a good one. Thanks! :)

Comment: I think there are no easy answer :/ I'm goint to make jQuery lib allowing things like this in near future.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataToPost = new Array();
var isButton1Clicked = false;
var isButton2Clicked = false;

//panel1
$("#save").click(function() {
  isButton1Clicked = true;
  dataToPost['panel'] = btoa($('#blob1').val());
  checkAndSubmit();
});
//panel2
$("#save").click(function() {
  isButton2Clicked = true;
  dataToPost['panel2_amount'] = $('#multi').val() * $('#multi2').val() + 1;
  dataToPost['crc32'] = crc32($('#blob2').val());
  checkToSubmit();
});


//some magic function
function checkToSubmit() {
 //make only ONE ajax request, saving data from all panels
 if (isButton1Clicked && isButton2Clicked) {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST'
     data: dataToPost
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: if you want to handle the response differently for each button, then you can supply a callback as the third argument to the function.

Comment: thank you for answer but this will post AJAX each time. I want to post only one request.

Comment: some global variable wich will be appended by every .click() event according to current panel business logic.

Comment: some global variable wich will be appended by every .click() event ... that doesn't make any sense. if you want help, you have to explain things more fully. one sentence that doesn't make sense isn't good enough. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i edited my answer above. hopefully that's what you want to do?